# ¿Cómo paso como variable un elemento de un select?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Quiero pasar una variable de html que se encuentra dentro de un select, este es el código html: (esta dentro de un formaluri con metodo POST)

```
<td>Autor</td>
                <td>

                    <select name="select" id="" class="form-control">
                        <?php 
                        $myrow = $obj->llenarLista("autor");
                            foreach ($myrow as $row) {
                                # code...

                         ?>

                    <option  value=" <?php echo $row["id_autor"];  ?>"><?php echo $row["autor"]; ?>

                    </option>

                         <?php

                                } 

                        ?>


                            </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>

                    <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="editar" value="Editar"></td>
```

Este es el archivo que debe de recibir la variable que tiene que recibir :

```
if(isset($_POST["editar"])){
        $id = $_POST["id_libro"];
        $where = array("id_libro"=>$id);
        $myArray = array(
            "nombre" => $_POST["nombre"],
            "autor" => $_POST["autor"] //ACA DEBE IR EL ELEMENTO SELECCCIONADO DEL SELECT
            );
        if ($obj->actualizar_libros("libro", $where, $myArray)) {
            # code...
            header("location:index.php?msg=Libro actualizado exitosamente");
        }
```

Comment: Definiste un formulario para enviar la informacion?

Comment: Si tengo un formulario, tiene el metodo POST, por ahorrar tiempo no coloque todo el codigo.

Answer (score 1):

Aqui no hay mucho que hacer, seguro se te paso, corrige esta linea en tu html:

```
<select name="select" id="" class="form-control">
```

por esta, que modifica **name="select"** por **name="autor"**

```
<select name="autor" id="" class="form-control">
```